# Which countries with single payer healthcare ban duplicative coverage?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, democratic-party, health-insurance

A single payer healthcare system is a system where all citizens have government health insurance.  Now most countries with single payer healthcare allow people to buy supplemental private insurance, though some have restrictions on what that supplemental insurance can cover.

In any case, several 2020 Democratic Presidential candidates, including Bernie Sanders and Elizabeth Warren, support a single-payer healthcare system where supplemental private insurance plans are not allowed to offer duplicative coverage, i.e. they’re not allowed to cover any of the same benefits that the government plan covers.  They’re only allowed to cover benefits not covered by the government plan.

My question is, which countries with single payer healthcare have a similar ban on duplicative coverage?  I think Canada may be one.  Are there any others?

Comment: In a lot of cases duplicate cover is simply pointless so it doesn't exist. If you already have a government mandated insurance that pays for a certain procedure, why would you pay extra to get the exact same procedure? If you have mandated health insurance, all other offers are supplementary or offer to do a slightly difference procedure for the same illness.

Comment: It's unlikely to affect the answers, but for some single payer healthcare systems (eg. "Beveridge model") the word "provision" at the end of the first line would be more representative than "insurance".

Comment: Are there any good sources for how the ban is enforced? E.g. if I want a private hospital to perform childbirth would I not be allowed to purchase that service? I have not heard about a rule like that in Europe.

Comment: Does " duplicative" mean "the same services at the same hospitals" or "the same services, but potentially at different hospitals with shorter waiting lists"?

Comment: @MSalters The first one would be pointless so nobody would ever buy it. In  economics it's assumed that people are generally smart and willing to do lots of  research and calculation before buying anything (even though this is untrue). Therefore, it's the second one.

Comment: @user253751: This is the Politics SE. I agree that the first sort is pointless, but that might be precisely why some governments outlaw it. It would be a ban on misleading advertising.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle That's not the rule described here. What is being prohibited is selling a certain type of insurance policy. You can still go to any private hospital you want.

Comment: @quarague; You wouldn’t pay extra to get the exact same care. You’d pay extra to better care more quickly than what the government-mandated plan offers. For example, if you need a joint replacement and you don’t want to be placed on a waiting list. A Canadian who can afford it can go to the US for that procedure and schedule it for next week with the doctor of their choosing rather than 6 months from now with the default doctor at the location closest to them.

Comment: @quarague It’s not pointless at all, in many single-payer countries people use private insurance to get procedures and other services done with less wait times.  That’s because the private insurance company may pay doctors and hospitals higher reimbursement rates than the government does.  That’s why Sanders and Warren want to ban duplicative coverage, because either the government would have to raise reimbursement rates to compete or you’d have a tiered system where rich people who can afford private insurance would be prioritized over poor people for the same care.

Comment: @MSalters The first sort is not pointless at all.  See my comment above.

Comment: @WesSayeed, in to your comment to quarague you mention "better care", but your example fails to describe the care as" better" - was that intentional? Are you asserting that the government plan provides sub-standard care?

Comment: Germany might qualify (but I don't understand the question well enough to make this an answer) - if you are qualified for private healthcare in the first place (either you're freelance/independent contractor, or your salary exceeds a certain threshold) then while you could in theory have both mandatory and private health insurance at the same time, only one of them would be allowed to pay for a procedure. So you can have both, but only one would actually kick in (does that meet the gist of the question?). You would have to be crazy to do that, though, so it's no practical concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [a document from OECD Health Statistic detailing the kinds of private health insurances](http://stats.oecd.org/wbos/fileview2.aspx?IDFile=e11b92da-6cc5-4cea-afe9-1d4cce02e5a4) available in countries where public health insurance is provided. The document defines three kinds of private health insurance:

- **Duplicate** where coverage is available for risks also covered by public health insurance. This would allow someone to choose to e.g. have their operation done in a private clinic.
- **Complementary** where coverage is available for additional costs of a healthcare treatment partially covered by public healthcare - for example if public healthcare only covered 90% of the cost this would pay for the other 10%
- **Supplementary** This would cover treatments not provided by public healthcare.

The coverage the question asks about is Duplicate. The list of countries where duplicate coverage is not available is:

- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- Czech Republic
- Denmark
- Estonia
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Hungary
- Japan
- Korea
- Luxembourg
- Netherlands
- Poland
- Portugal
- Slovakia
- Slovenia
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- Turkey

I've omitted some edge cases, for example where health coverage is provided by private insurers but is mandated by the state.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. I don't know about the other countries, but in Sweden it is definitely possible to buy private health insurance that covers the same procedures that the national health insurance program covers. Those allow the insured to bypass the queues that exist in the public system.

Comment: The link is fixed.

Comment: Not sure I understand the final comment: Health insurance in the Netherlands is in fact provided by private insurers but mandated by the state. Also, shouldn't “Duplicate where coverage is available for risks also covered by **private** health insurance.” actually read “Duplicate where coverage is available for risks also covered by **public** health insurance.“?

Comment: Not available is not the same as banned though.

Comment: @Relaxed Fixed the mistake in "Duplicate".

Answer (score 2):

[Canada is indeed one.](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/health-care-system/reports-publications/health-care-system/canada.html)

> Under most provincial and territorial laws, private insurers are restricted from offering coverage that duplicates that of the publicly funded plans, but they can compete in the supplementary coverage market.

[Countries where it is permitted include Finland, Italy, New Zealand, Ireland and the United Kingdom, Australia and France.](https://www.iedm.org/3293-duplicate-private-health-insurance-permissible-under-the-canada-health-act-says-the-montreal-economic-institute/)

> Duplicate insurance is available in many countries, including Finland, Italy, New Zealand, Ireland and the United Kingdom. In some places it attracts a large share of the population, as in Australia, where nearly 45% of citizens hold this type of insurance. In other countries, its role is marginal because of competition from public health insurance, especially where waiting lists are almost non-existent, as in France.

Comment: Are there any countries other than Canada that ban it?

Comment: I don't know. This is what I know. I'm hoping others will know more.

Comment: What about Norway and Denmark?

Comment: This answer is really superceded by my other one. I'm going to leave this one here for a bit, but I'll delete it if the other one is more useful

Answer (score 1):

For Denmark a lot of companies have an extra health insurance. It e.g. means workers can get an operation faster or get something that isn't covered (e.g. physiotherapy).

I don't know about other European countries